# Extraer string desde resources en LinkedHashMap

Tags: android, string

Tengo un listado hecho en un `LinkedHashMap`. Lo he logrado de la siguiente forma:

```
List<String> Obj = new ArrayList<String>();
    Obj.add("Text1");
    Obj.add("Text2");
    Obj.add("Text3");
    Obj.add("Text4");
    Obj.add("Text10");
```

El problema es que no sé cómo extraer este texto en comillas desde un xml resources que tengo. ¿Alguna solución? ¿Cómo podría hacerse?

He intentado de varias formas pero no he logrado dar con la solución.

Comment: ese texto lo tienes en un .xml? porque no agregas esa parte.

Comment: estaría bien si publicas el xml del que quieres obtener la información (o un segmento), como comenta Jorgesys, tienes un arraylist, tu pregunta parece que no esta bien planteada

Answer (score 0):

Lo que tienes no es un `LinkedHashMap`, es un `ArrayList` de Strings,

```
   List<String> Obj = new ArrayList<String>();
    Obj.add("Text1");
    Obj.add("Text2");
    Obj.add("Text3");
    Obj.add("Text4");
    Obj.add("Text10");
```

Para extraer los datos puedes obtener el elemento dentro del listado mediante su indice, por ejemplo, si deseas obtener el primer elemento, (recuerda que inician con indice 0) :

```
String valor = Obj.get(0);
```

realizando lo anterior obtendrías el valor `"Text1"`.

También puedes obtener todos los valores dentro del `ArrayList` mediante un bucle, de esta forma:

```
    for(String string: Obj){
        Log.i("ArrayList", "valor: " + so );
    }
```